# Killing threads from completion service?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, completion-service

### Problem

I am using a completion service and spawning child threads to perform some ETL.
As I debug in my IDE and then stop all processes, I notice I still have a bunch of zombie threads killing my CPU. This is due to the fact that I'm not terminating the child threads properly.

### Minimum Example

```java
  Future<Boolean> future = completionService.submit(conversionProcessor);
  boolean isCompleted = false;
  while (!isCompleted && !closed.get()) {
    try {
      isCompleted = future.get(CONSUMER_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL,
          TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Wait until heartbeat interval exceeds
      if (isCompleted) {
        // do some things here
        future.cancel(true);
        break;
      }
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      // Used to keep consumer alive in the cluster
      consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(CONSUMER_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL)); // does heart-beat
    } catch (CancellationException e) {
      future.cancel(true);
      break;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      future.cancel(true);
      break;
    } catch (WakeupException we) {
      future.cancel(true);
      break;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      future.cancel(true);
      break;
    }
```

### Thoughts

Essentially, I submit my `Callable<Boolean>` to my completion service.

```java
    ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
```

If I stop the debugger, this thread is presumably still running. I *just* added this `future.cancel(true)` piece, which seems to have stopped continuously uploaded files from my child thread, but I still see these java processes running on my activity monitor.

I'm wondering how I should be thinking about this? I want the callable as it tells me *when* the underlying ETL has completed or not (true/false)

edit:
future.cancel actually seems to be helping quite a bit.. Is this what I want to be using?

Comment: Note that running your conversionProcessor in a separate thread and then in the meantime keeping the main thread busy as well in a while loop checking if the other thread has done its work is very inefficient. You're now keeping two threads occupied where it could be one. Much better is to just use, for example, a CompletableFuture and then compose whatever work you want to do based on the result of the process in a CompletableFuture.thenAccept.

Comment: I have to have the main thread in a while loop as Kafka cluster requires a heartbeat and long-running ETL will cause consumer group rebalances if exceeds 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are done with your `CompletionService` you need to shutdown underlying executor so you need to do the following

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
ExecutorCompletionService<Boolean> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(es);
```

And a the end call

```
es.shutdown();
es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. Should I do the future.cancel as well, or does that happen implicitly?

Comment: Once the future has completed it's done, it does not need to be canceled. You only need to cancel the future if you want to interrupt the processing for some reason.

Comment: Does es.shutDown kill all futures?

Comment: No, it just marks the completion service as no longer usable.  New jobs added to a shutdown service will throw an error.  The existing jobs complete as normal after a call to `shutDown()`.  Read the docs please.

Comment: @Ryan there is a method `shutdownNow()` but you need to make your tasks "cancellable"
There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop
 processing actively executing tasks.  For example, typical
 implementations will cancel via {@link Thread#interrupt}, so any
 task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.